# Is this combinatorial seach problem NP-complete?

Tags: optimization, np-complete, reductions, combinatorics, complexity-classes

**The context**: Consider the following optimization problem. Let $f_1,\dots,f_L:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ arbitrary (continous) functions for $L>1$ and $x_k\in\mathbb{R}$  evolve according to
$$
x_{k+1} = f_{\sigma(k)}(x_k),
$$
given $x_0$, where $\sigma_k \in\{1,\dots,L\}$. We want to find $\sigma(0),\dots,\sigma(N-1)$ to minimize
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{N-1} x_k^2
$$
for some $N>0$. As far as I can tell, if the functions $f_1,\dots,f_L$ are arbitrary, then $x_k$ may lie virtually in any place in $\mathbb{R}$ and there won't be any aparent structure on the number of states that $x_k$ can have. Thus, it seems that there is no better solution but to try all combinations of $\sigma(0),\dots,\sigma(N-1)$, which grow as $L^N$, exponentially in $N$. This may be done, e.g., by building a tree where each level is a step $k$ and the posible choices $1,\dots,L$ are explored at each node. This "try all combinations" can be improved by some heuristics, but still I suspect that the combinatorial explosion problem is hard to be avoided if an exact solution is desired. This makes me think that we can show this problem to be NP-complete (in terms of the variable $N$).

As far as I know, to show that this problem is NP complete we need to reduce this problem to another problem in a "[list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_NP-complete_problems)" of NP complete problems. Unfortunately, I have just started reading on complexity theory and combinatoric optimization (mosty due to my need to solve a problem like this one) and I haven't managed to see if these problems are related to mine, particularly since I don't understand most of them (yet).

**Question:** If you are more familiar to the NP-complete problems list, do you see which one may be a good candidate to reduce my problem to?

**EDIT**: As noted in the comments, this problem isn't NP-complete since verifying the correctness of a solution is as hard as finding one. However, my goal was to show that this problem is indeed "hard" is some sense, by framing it under some of these complexity categories. If NP-completeness is not the right category, which one is it?

Comment: The problem is a little over my head but it sounds similar to the [Traveling Salesman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem).  Although I'm assuming you don't need all values of `\sigma` to be "visited".  Do you need to maximize the number of `sigma` terms while minimizing the sum of `x^2`?  So maybe not.  I'm out of my depth here.

Comment: Note two things: (i) your problem is not a decision problem and thus it can't be NPC and (ii) to show hardness, you need to reduce a hard problem to your problem and not vice versa.

Comment: When dealing with a very general problem, it is usually a good strategy to think about specific "corner cases". For instance, what if $L=1$? What if my function(s) take some very specific form? Does the problem then correspond to some better known problem?

Comment: Well if $L=1$ then, there is no need to choose $\sigma$ since it would be fixed. Another thing, if its not a decision problem, say how hard is it? My goal was to try to justify that finding a solution other tha  the brute force approach is "hard" in some sense. But if this problem cannot be understood in this discusion for decision problems, what can I try? Thanks!

Comment: 1. The problem is not well-formulated because you haven't described how the $f_i$ are represented in the input.  In fact, you can't represent an arbitrary function $f_i:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ in a finite number of bits, so there is a problem.  You'll need to specify a subclass of functions that can be finitely represented.  Also, working with $\mathbb{R}$ is messy; you probably should work with values that have a finite description.  2. It's not NP-complete, for the reasons others have explained, but it might be NP-hard.  Read about that concept.